# ViewPager - Android Error setCurrentItem(int,boolean) while sending data from fragment to activity

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager, fragment

**I am using NonSwipeableViewPager**

**NonSwipeableViewPager.Java**

```
public class NonSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {
    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }
}
```

**I have MainActivity in Which I am using this ViewPager with Two Fragments**

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.advancetechindia.fragmenttest.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <com.advancetechindia.fragmenttest.NonSwipeableViewPager
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/viewpager_id"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private NonSwipeableViewPager viewpager;
private FragmentFirst fragmentFirst=new FragmentFirst();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewpager=(NonSwipeableViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager_id);
    viewpager.setAdapter(new SamplePagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager()));
}

public void getData(String s) {
    Log.d("TAG",s);
    viewpager.setCurrentItem(1,true);
}

public class SamplePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SamplePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        /** Show a Fragment based on the position of the current screen */

        if (position==0) {
            return new FragmentFirst();
        } else return new FragmentTwo();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

} }
```

**frag_one.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/et_id"
            android:hint="texthere"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btn_id"
            android:text="Fire"
            android:onClick="GetString"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[frag_one.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCAGs.png)

**FragmentFirst.java**

```
public class FragmentFirst extends Fragment {

private EditText et;
private Button btn;
private MainActivity mainact;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_one, container,
            false);
    mainact=new MainActivity();

    et=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.et_id);
    btn=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_id);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String abc=et.getText().toString();
            Log.d("TAG",abc);
            mainact.getData(abc);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
} }
```

Also, i have another Fragment--- FragmentTwo.java

when I click on Fire Button it invokes

```
getData(String s)
```

method of MainActivity where I got the string but it shows error on

```
viewpager.setCurrentItem(int,boolean)
```

Please let me get out of this hurdle. Thanks

**Error**

> 10:54:46.205 31492-31492/com.advancetechindia.fragmenttest
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: com.advancetechindia.fragmenttest, PID: 31492
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   com.advancetechindia.fragmenttest.NonSwipeableViewPager.setCurrentItem(int,
>   boolean)' on a null object reference
>   at
>   com.advancetechindia.fragmenttest.MainActivity.getData(MainActivity.java:30)
>   atcom.advancetechindia.fragmenttest.FragmentFirst$1.onClick(FragmentFirst.java:37)at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5612)at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22285)at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                              at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)

Comment: "mainact=new MainActivity()"? Whats this? never ever create an Activity instance with `new` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mainact=new MainActivity();` is create new object and `ViewPager` alive in Old object so you need to access old object of `MainActivity`

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).getData(abc);
```

Comment: Thanx a Lot Guyzz !! It Works !!

Comment: most welcome !! happy coding... and if you satisfy with answer then give up vote.

Answer (score 1):

replace this in your **FragmentFirst.java**

```
mainact.getData(abc);
```

with

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).getData(abc);
```